# How would I go about getting this code to shuffle the deck two more times to complete the card trick?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, shuffle

Right now, I'm working on a 21 card trick and I've run into this error that I can't seem to crack.

```
def combine_columns_basedoncard(split_card_deck,TotalCardDeck):
   
    split_card_deck = deal_deck_columns(TotalCardDeck)
    for i in range(3):
        card_deck = []
        card_deck2 = []
        card_deck3 = []
        for i in range(0, 21, 3):
            card_deck.append(subdeck[0 + i])
            card_deck2.append(subdeck[1 + i])
            card_deck3.append(subdeck[2 + i])

        DealedCards = card_deck, card_deck2, card_deck3
        Choice()
        
        if (Choice == 1):
            subdeck.extend(card_deck2)
            subdeck.extend(card_deck)
            subdeck.extend(card_deck3)
        elif (Choice == 2):
            subdeck.extend(card_deck)
            subdeck.extend(card_deck2)
            subdeck.extend(card_deck3)
        else:
            subdeck.extend(card_deck)
            subdeck.extend(card_deck3)
            subdeck.extend(card_deck2)

        print(DealedCards)
```

Here is a function that shuffles a deck and then the user can choose which pile/subdeck their card is in, however, this code will only shuffle once and then never again and print the same list and I can't really see why this happens, or how I would go about shuffling the deck again to complete the 21 card trick. If anyone could give some suggestions that would be very much appreciated!

edit:

```
def Choice():
    VaildChoice = False
    ColumnChoice = ""
    while(not VaildChoice):
        ColumnChoice = input("Which column is your card in? 1, 2 or 3 ")
        if("1" in ColumnChoice or "2" in ColumnChoice or "3" in ColumnChoice):
            VaildChoice = True
        else:
            print("Invaild choice")
    return ColumnChoice
```

Added the choice() to give a better idea of the code!

Comment: can we get a little more for a [mcve]?

Comment: did you confuse subdeck and split_card_deck?

Comment: If `Choice` is a function, such that `Choice()` is something that you can reasonably do - then `Choice == 1` or `Choice == 2` cannot possibly be true.  Perhaps you wanted to save the result of the function in a variable, and then compare that value to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are extending the subdeck. When you extend the subdeck the new elements get inserted at the end. In the next iteration your subdeck length has extended but the first set of cards are still the same and they were never replaced.

To fix this initialize subdeck to empty list after Choice()

Also your outer loop iterator and inner loop iterator are both named i. Check that usage.